# Solving system of ODEs with extra parameter

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I would like to solve a $2\times 2$ system of the form
$$\frac{d}{d\theta}T=TA,\quad T(0)=Id$$
where $\theta$ is real and $A$ is of the form
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & \frac{e^{-i \theta}}{\lambda}\\ \frac{1}{36}e^{-i\theta}\left(9\lambda + 2(\lambda-1)^2 (6\cos{\theta} + \cos{2\theta} + 6)\right) & 0\end{pmatrix},$$
with $\lambda$ a free parameter in the **unit circle**.

In particular I'm interested in obtaining numeric solutions at $\theta=2\pi$ depending on the extra parameter $\lambda$. I'm fairly new using *Mathematica*, and this is what I have tried so far:

```
T[θ_] = {{T11[θ], T12[θ]}, {T21[θ], T22[θ]}};
A[θ_] = {
    {0, E^(-I θ)/λ},
    {1/36 E^(-I θ) (9 λ + 2 (-1 + λ)^2 (6 + 6 Cos[θ] + Cos[2 θ])), 0}
};
sys = {T'[θ] == T[θ].A[θ]};
```

The previous code sets the system that I want to solve and now I try to solve numerically. First I've tried

```
NSol = NDSolve[
    {sys, T11[0] == 1, T12[0] == 0, T21[0] == 0, T22[0] == 1},
    {T11[θ], T12[θ], T21[θ], T22[θ]},
    {θ},
    {θ, 0, 2 Pi}
];
```

which gives me the output

```
NDSolve::dupv: "Duplicate variable θ found in NDSolve[<<1>>]."
```

I have also tried

```
Nsol2 = ParametricNDSolve[
    {sys, T11[0] == 1, T12[0] == 0, T21[0] == 0, T22[0] == 1},
    {T11, T12, T21, T22},
    {θ, 0, 2 Pi},
    {λ}
];
```

which gives me as output $T_{11},\dots,T_{22}$ as *ParametricFunction*s depending on each other and on $\lambda$.

I don't know if this is the right approach and, if so, how to extract a numeric expression depending on $\lambda$ from the last output - all that I've seen in the documentation are examples that are plotted for specific values of the parameter. Any help is much appreciated.

**EDIT**

> Following the comments in one of the answers I'd like to explain further: the output that I would like to obtain is some sort of function depending of the parameter $\lambda$ that I can manipulate afterwards. Say for instance, computing the series expansion of powers of $\lambda$ of my solution. I don't know how to treat the *ParametricFunction* that I obtain to do such computations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to obtain the series expansion of the matrix components. First, using a tweaked version (solving for `t[2π]` instead of `t`) of JM's formulation:

```
A[θ_] = {
    {0, E^(-I θ)/λ},
    {1/36 E^(-I θ) (9 λ + 2 (-1 + λ)^2 (6 + 6 Cos[θ] + Cos[2 θ])), 0}
};

pf = ParametricNDSolveValue[
    {
    t'[θ] == t[θ].A[θ], t[0] == IdentityMatrix[2]
    },
    t[2π],
    {θ, 0, 2π},
    λ
];
```

Then, `pf` will return the matrix value at $\theta = 2 \pi$. For example:

```
pf[1]
pf[Exp[I Pi/3]]
```

> {{1. + 3.62818*10^-9 I, 
>     6.82646*10^-8 - 5.73536*10^-9 I}, {1.70661*10^-8 - 1.43384*10^-9 I, 
>     1. + 3.62818*10^-9 I}}
>
> {{0.985595 + 1.17074 I, -0.425572 + 0.737112 I}, {-0.788363 - 1.36549 I, 
>     0.985595 - 1.17074 I}}

Finding the series expansion is simple:

```
DecimalForm[Series[pf[λ], {λ, 1, 5}], {4,4}] //TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  1.0000 & 6.2830 \\
>  1.5710 & 1.0000 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)+\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  0.0000+0.0000 i & -6.2830+0.0000 i \\
>  1.5710+0.0000 i & 0.0000+0.0000 i \\
> \end{array}
> \right) (\lambda -1)+\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  0.0000-0.7869 i & 0.6691-0.0000 i \\
>  0.8799+0.0000 i & -0.0000+0.7869 i \\
> \end{array}
> \right) (\lambda -1)^2+\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  0.0000+0.7869 i & -1.3380+0.0000 i \\
>  0.0000+0.0000 i & 0.0000-0.7869 i \\
> \end{array}
> \right) (\lambda -1)^3+\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  -0.0152-0.4524 i & 1.8410-0.0000 i \\
>  -0.5708-0.0000 i & -0.0152+0.4524 i \\
> \end{array}
> \right) (\lambda -1)^4+\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  0.0305+0.1179 i & -2.1780+0.0000 i \\
>  0.5708-0.0000 i & 0.0305-0.1179 i \\
> \end{array}
> \right) (\lambda -1)^5+O\left((\lambda -1)^6\right)$

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell, you did everything right in your second approach. Classically, *Mathematica* returns lists of rules as results of solving functions, but in this case, I find this tradition rather confusing and prefer to use `ParametricNDSolveValue`; it returns a `ParametricFunction` object that, when applied to a numerical parameter, returns a list of 4 `InterpolatingFunction` for your 4 functions.

```
T[θ_] = {{T11[θ], T12[θ]}, {T21[θ], T22[θ]}};
A[θ_] = {{0, E^(-I θ)/λ}, {1/36 E^(-I θ) (9 λ + 2 (-1 + λ)^2 (6 + 6 Cos[θ] + Cos[2 θ])), 0}};
sys = {T'[θ] == T[θ].A[θ]};

Tsol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{sys, T11[0] == 1, T12[0] == 0, 
    T21[0] == 0, T22[0] == 1},
   {T11, T12, T21, T22},
   {θ, 0, 2 Pi},
   {λ}
   ];
```

In order to obtain the numerical values for all the solutions at `θ = 2 Pi` for a given parameter, say `λ = 0.1`, you may use `Through`:

```
Through[Tsol[0.1][2. Pi]]
```

> {-0.545795 + 1.00532 I, -1.43497 - 7.95125*10^-7 I, -0.215035 - 
>     2.80298*10^-8 I, -0.545795 - 1.00532 I}

In order to make that into a function, you may use

```
f = λ \[Function] Through[Tsol[λ][2. Pi]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Only the last step differs from what I'd like to obtain. What I would like to see is a function depending on $\lambda$, not the evaluation at a single point.

Answer (score 3):

For this case, you don't even need to write out the components of your matrix function:

```
pf = ParametricNDSolveValue[{t'[θ] == t[θ].{{0, Exp[-I θ]/λ},
                                            {Exp[-I θ] (9 λ + 2 (λ - 1)^2
                                             (6 Cos[θ] + Cos[2 θ] + 6))/36, 0}},
                             t[0] == IdentityMatrix[2]}, t, {θ, 0, 2 π}, λ,
                             Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"];

sol = pf[(3 + 4 I)/5];

ParametricPlot[ReIm[Tr[sol[θ]]], {θ, 0, 2 π}]
```

[image: some curve]

```
ParametricPlot[ReIm[Det[sol[θ]]], {θ, 0, 2 π}]
```

[image: some other curve]

You can even make a plot where the parameter is varying:

```
Plot[Re[Tr[pf[Exp[I ϕ]][2 π]]], {ϕ, 0, 2 π}]
```

[image: yet another curve]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could I see the solution as a function of $\lambda$ instead? I suppose is something possible to do...

Comment: That is what the third plot is; I let $\lambda=\exp(i\varphi)$ (quote "with $\lambda$ a free parameter in the **unit circle**") and plotted the real part of the trace of the matrix.

Comment: Sure, but I'd like to manipulate it further. Not just see its plot. See my point?

Comment: You make no mention of what kind of manipulations you like to do in your question, so no, I do not see.

Comment: For example, can I get the solution as a function of $\lambda$? Or as a series expansion of powers of $\lambda$?

Comment: Ah, the series expansion is a more interesting problem. You should edit your question to include that. Otherwise, one can trivially do `edu[λ_] := pf[λ][2 π]`.