# Transforming ParametricFunction in expression depending on the parameter

Tags: differential-equations, parametric-functions

As a result of solving an ODE system using `ParametricNDSolveValue` I obtain 4 functions, each of them a *ParametricFunction* depending on the parameter specified in `ParametricNDSolveValue`.

Even though what I want looks 'simple' to me, I've searched through the documentation and this site with no success, so here goes my question:

> Can I transform my solution *ParametricFunction* into an expression of some kind? The motivation is manipulating this expression, and this may involve different software.

If that's not possible, is there any other way in *Mathematica* to solve a $2\times 2$ system of ODEs at a point with a free parameter? [Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/194251/solving-system-of-odes-with-extra-parameter)'s the question where I first asked about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Towards your highlighted question: The answer is no. `ParametricFunction` objects are actually not pure functions but rather information containers that enable *Mathematica* to quickly generate `InterpolatingFunction`s once a numerical parameter is supplied. There is usually a complicated numerical solver involved in this and so there is no simple analytical expression into which a `ParametricFunction` could be transformed to.

Similar are `InterpolatingFunction` objects: They represent piecewise-polynomial functions or rather enough information so that numerical evaluation of the underlying functions can be done (more or less) efficiently. While it *would* be possible to turn an `InterpolatingFunction` into a `Piecewise` expression, it would not be meaningful as there are usually thousands (or even millions) of cases to be distinguished; the output expression would be nothing a human mind would find elevating.

If you look for symbolic solutions to ODE then try `DSolve` instead of `NDSolve`. But do not expect that you find a symbolic solution in general. In fact, most ODEs do not have closed form solutions.

Comment: Incidentally, given a `ParametricFunction` with variable `x` and parameter `a`, is there a good way to fix `x` and generate an `InterpolatingFunction` dependent on `a`? Or rather a bivariate `InterpolatingFunction` dependent on both `x` and `a`? What is the difference between a bivariate `InterpolatingFunction` and a `ParametricFunction`? Sorry for tandem questioning, I hope these are related close enough to not be offensive.

Comment: From [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/67642/72025) I believe using `FunctionInterpolate` is not very desirable? What would be an idiomatic alternative?

Comment: You can simply sample a `ParametricFunction` on a regular grid and use that to construct an `InterpolatingFunction`. Of course, a bit of accuracy will be lost, but maybe that is acceptable for you.

Comment: It is tricky for me, as I actually need to do an improper integration with this function. so the result is really sensitive to the vincinity of the singularity.